# Prove that any string formed from the alphabet {0, 1} that has an equal amount of 0's and 1's can always be written as 0x1y or 1x0y

Tags: context-free-grammar

This has me stumped. How can you prove that for the alphabet $\Sigma = \{0, 1\}$, any string $w \in \Sigma^\star$ with an equal amount of 0's and 1's will always have either the format $0x1y$ or $1x0y$ (where $x$ and $y$ are substrings also $\in \Sigma^\star $ and have an equal amount of 0's and 1's) ?

I see that $x$ and $y$ can both be either empty or another, simpler inductive case of $w$, but I have trouble writing out this proof formally.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose without loss of generality that $w$ starts with a $0$. Then, count along the letters in $w$, and keep track of the number of zeroes you have seen minus the number of ones you have seen. So if $w = 000110111100$, then your counting goes $1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 2, 1, 0, -1, -2, -1, 0$. Clearly in the end you must have gotten to 0, since there are an equal number of zeroes and ones. This means that at some point you must *drop* to zero, that is, at some point you must count $1, 0$. You can see this in our example above.

When you get to that 1, you have counted a substring which has the initial 0, and then after that an equal number of zeroes and ones; and because you then drop to 0, there must be another 1 after that substring. Thus we collect the substring to get $x$, and we write $w = 0x1y$, where $y$ is whatever is left. In our example, we get $w = 0(001101)1(1100)$.

Answer (score 0):

The first character of the string has to be a $0$ or a $1$. Since the number of $0$'s is equal to the number of $1$'s, if the first character is $0$, there has to be a $1$ further ahead and if the first character is $1$, there has to be a $0$ further ahead.